# How to display text link context instead of URL when long press on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile-browser

I've seen sites when long pressed the text link URL on mobile browser, eg. Chrome I've tried, it'll display default system pop-up navigation showing the text link context instead of the actual long non-human readable URL/query string.

How can this be done in HTML?  or if this is a CSS/JS snippet?

Comment: you going to need to use a plugin such as hammer js to detect longpress and take appropriate action http://hammerjs.github.io/   -- http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-press/

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/4k2zhs0L/

You can use the `setTimeout` function

Comment: Sorry i fix the contextmenu bug,before if you using mobile long press it will show the contextmenu,but now won't

Comment: I'm testing your example on a mobile device using the Chrome browser.  When long press the link, it's displaying the URL.  Instead, I would like it to display the text link, `Can you long press me please?`  I also don't need this to have js pop up on desktop browser.

Comment: I help you update the code,if you still got any problem or anythings want to add in this,just call me KDX

Comment: Thank you for the update, Felix.  But I think there is some misunderstanding.  I'm not referring at the `alert` popup display.  When long press the link in mobile Chrome browser, there's a menu showing: `URL`, `Open`, `Add to Reading List`, `Copy`, and `Cancel`.  I'm referring to the `URL` part, that I want to display the text link context `Can you long press me please?` instead of actual `URL` which may contain long query string.

Comment: If you got time please contact me at http://chat.stackexchange.com,and if you are up there,please leave me know you are there by leaving a comment here thanks